# preg_match(): Text range out of order on PHP Regex

Tags: java, php, regex

I want to convert java regex to php regex. But I get error "- Text range out of order"

This is JAVA regex

```
"[^\\u0020-\\u007F\u011f\u00fc\u015f\u00f6\u00e7\u011e\u00dc\u015e\u0130\u00d6\u00c7\u0131]";
```

This is PHP regex

```
preg_replace("/[^\\x{0020}-\\x{007F}\\x{011f}\\x{00fc}\\x{015f}\\x{00f6}\\x{00e7}\\x{011e}\\x{00dc}\\x{015e}\\x{0130}\\x{00d6}\\x{00c7}\\x{0131}]/i","",".çşüiğıyuasdfaadsff");
```

I get following error "- Text range out of order"

Any Help?

Comment: Where do you get this error? When pasting the regex string into regex101.com?

Comment: Try adding the u modifier after i

Comment: Not sure why you get that error: On ideone, I get this `PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 26 in /home/ivJ7iQ/prog.php on line 3` http://ideone.com/lbZv74

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the regex engine interprets the input string and the regex as an array of bytes in PHP. You should get an error about the character value too large, since `\x{011f}` or `\x{011e}` are larger than 255 (the maximum value of one byte).

To match Unicode code points, rather than arbitrary byte sequences, use `u` flag to turn on UTF mode.

```
$re = '~[^\x{0020}-\x{007F}\x{011f}\x{00fc}\x{015f}\x{00f6}\x{00e7}\x{011e}\x{00dc}\x{015e}\x{0130}\x{00d6}\x{00c7}\x{0131}]~u';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU4lG6/2)

Comment: *In PHP use this regex:* Why should OP *use* his regex? What did you changed and why?